# Is the Kawamall DMTF 6pin microphone usable with the Kenwood TK-805D radio?

Tags: kenwood, microphone

I have a [Kenwood TK-805D](http://www.rfstuff.com/manuals/805Dman.pdf) commercial radio, which I am using for UHF ham operation.

For repeater usage, with AllStar, IRLP, and Echolink, I need a DTMF mic for it.

I did a search on the internet, and found this pinout:

[image]

The diagram claims that the radio has an 8v potential at pin 1, but I measured 12 instead.

[This link](http://highfields-arc.co.uk/constructors/micwiring/k/kwt/kwt19.htm) displays a confusion between knowing if it is 12v or 8v output, and says from different sources, mixed data is shown.

I am looking at a [particular DTMF mic found on eBay,](https://web.archive.org/web/20141013221846/http://www.ebay.com/itm/KAWAMALL-DTMF-6Pin-Mic-For-Kenwood-TK-7360-TK8360-TKR730-TKR-830-TKR-740-TKR-840-/121439698322?pt=US_Radio_Comm_Antennas&hash=item1c465ebd92) which claims it works on 6-pin Radios, but doesn't have the TK-805 on the list. Weirdly, it has the TK-760 on the list, which is on the pinout diagram above.

Would the mic above work? If not, is there any other mics at a reasonable price that would work, if not, I have some adjustable voltage regulators that I could calibrate for 8 volts, and solder it in at the 12v pin. Would one of those work?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't 12V under no load and drops to 8V under load? Consider adding an appropriately powered resistor and measuring the voltage under a load (similar to that of a microphone if you can). If you have a microphone already, a breakout cable of some kind may allow you to make that measurement with the existing microphone hooked up.

Comment: Well I do know one thing, i fried a trace on the circuit board by accidentally shorting when I was testing. The trace looked like a direct 12v hookup, and the voltage was the EXACT same as the battery, no voltage drop measured between the battery + and the output of the radio +

Comment: I just got a message from the ebay seller stating the mic "should" work with it, don't know if I should believe them or not though.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think your title edit is not quite right. The particular product named is more "research before asking", whereas the question is looking for anything that would work or could be made to work.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO I'm not so sure, honestly. **Skyler 440**, if you feel my edit changed your intent, by all means roll back or edit further.

Comment: https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/how-are-dtmf-tones-sent-through-a-mic?rq=1 shows the same pinout for an entirely different Kenwood radio.  It might be a standard pin configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the Service Manual for the TK-805D and it shows +13.8 Vdc on pin 1 and +5 Vdc on pin 6.  Mind you, these readings are hand written by whom ever posted this manual.

Do you have the part number off the back of the microphone?

I know this is a 3 year old post and hopefully you ere able to get your answer.

I love this little radio, just don't like the microphone as it's the old style Kenwood mic (overly large).

Rod
KC7CJO