# How are DTMF tones sent through a mic?

Tags: microphone

In the following diagrams, a microphone pinout is shown for several radios which have DTMF mics that work with them.

How is DTMF sent to the radio without a pin designated "DTMF"? Is it through the microphone audio, or is it through the up/down pins, which are used only when the radio is not transmitting? Or is there some other way to send DTMF?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

DTMF is an **audio-frequency based** signaling system that sends tone pairs as audible frequencies,. Most DTMF microphones send the tones as though they were ordinary **microphone audio** to be transmitted, so in the diagrams you have shown, the tones will use the same "MIC AUDIO" or "TX AUDIO" path as when you are talking into the mic.

(And if you're interested in *what* those audio frequencies are, [Wikipedia's page on DTMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) shows the full tone matrix and a few other details about the signaling system.)